# StartActivity in Custom ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android

I'm setting an `onClick` to my `TextView` called phone in my custom `ListView`. When the `TextView` is clicked, I would like for it to open up Android's Dial screen. I passed the Context of my Activity to my Custom Adapter Java Class but the app still keeps crashing every time I click on my `TextView`. The following code consists of the constructor as well as the last few methods in my Custom Adapter Java Class:

```
    public CustomAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String>n,ArrayList<String>nums, ArrayList<String>e){
           context = c;
           phoneNumbers = nums;
           names = n;
           emails = e;
           inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

...

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_custom_row,null);
        TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactNumber);

        phone.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.customRowContactNumber:{
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            context.startActivity(i);//I passed the context to my constructor
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, thank you. Here is the log cat error:

```
09-21 17:48:49.451    2003-2003/com.markfeldman.mydoggydays E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.markf.dogdays, PID: 2003
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1238)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1225)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:323)
        at com.markfeldman.mydoggydays.CustomAdapter.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:71)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure here is where you want to start the activity you can just add

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

then start it as you were,

```
context.startActivity(i);
```

It looks like the context your passing isn't the context of an Activity which is why it's giving you the warning.  If you're sure, you can do what @fixmycode suggested with changing the class declaration.

Comment: This is what I'm passing to my CustomAdapter Class when it's instantiated in my other Activity called Contacts: customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),names,phoneNums,emails); I tried passing the class's activity but the app won't work right. For example, when I pass customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Contacts.this,names,phoneNums,emails); My Inflater doesn't work properly, that's why I'm passing getApplicationContext() as one of my parameters to the CustomAdapter class. Is this bad to do?

Comment: You should (in my opinion) be passing the activity, so using `Contacts.this`; at least that is what I do.  If your inflater isn't quite working correctly you could look at why that is the case independently.  I would really suggest checking out some of the Vogella tutorials on topics such as this - they're really great resources on how to do things, and with nice coding style too!  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

In your class declaration:

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ...){
    Activity myActivity = activity;
    ...
}
```

In your onClick method:

```
myActivity.startActivity(...);
```